# Writing a simulation code adding blocks in chain

Tags: python, blockchain

What is wrong with this simulation code adding blocks in chain. I think the nonce value should be incremented in while loop before calculating the hash value in "mineBlock" function. Else once we get the proof of work succeeded. The nonce that we are going to assign to the block will be one number ahead of the correct nonce.

```py
import hashlib

class Block:
    def __init__(self, no, nonce, data, hashcode, prev):
        self.no=no
        self.nonce=nonce
        self.data=data
        self.hashcode=hash
        self.prev=prev

    def getStringVal():
        return self.no, self.nonce, self.data, self.hashcode, self.prev

class Blockchain:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chain=[]
        self.prefix="0000"

    def addNewBlock(self, data):
        no=len(self.chain)
        nonce=0

        if len(self.chain)==0:
            prev="0"
        else:
            prev=self.chain[-1].hashcode
        
        myHash hashlib.sha256(str(data).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        block=Block(no, nonce, data, myHash, prev)

        self.chain.append(block)

    def printBlockchain(self):
        chainDict={}
        for no in range(len(self.chain)):
            chainDict[no]=self.chain[no].getStringVal()
        print(chainDict)

    def mineChain(self):
        brokenLink=self.checkIfBroken

        if (brokenLink==None):
            pass
        else:
            for block in self.chain[brokenLink.no:]:
                print("Mining Block:" block.getStringVal())
                self.mineBlock(block)

    def mineBlock(self, block):
        nonce=0
        myHash=hashlib.sha256(str(nonce)+str(block.data)).encode('utf-8').hexdigest()
        while myHash[0:4]!=self.prefix:
            myHash=hashlib.sha256(str(nonce)+str(block.data)).encode('utf-8').hexdigest()
            nonce=nonce+1
        else:
            self.chain[block.no].hashcode=myHash
            self.chain[block.no].nonce=nonce
            if (block.no<len(self.chain)-1:
                self.chain[block.no+1].prev=myHash


    
    def checkIfBroken(self):
        for no in range(len(self.chain)):
            if (self.chain[no].hashcode[0:4]==self.prefix):
                pass
            else self.chain[no]

    def changeData(self, no, data):
        self.chain[no].data=data
        self.chain.[no].hashcode=myHash=hashlib.sha256(str(nonce)+str(block.data)).encode('utf-8').hexdigest()`enter code here`
```

Comment: The code you've posted is not valid Python (and not only due to the bad indentation). Please at least attempt to run your code before pasting it here.

Comment: What is the actual problem here? I couldn't understand it.